# mongoDB 32-bit 2GB limit, best practices

Tags: mongodb

Mongo newbie running 32-bit Mongo 2.0.1 on Windows XP.  No option at present to run 64-bit.

I want to use Mongo to map-reduce a set of 60 files, each a monthly snapshot of the same 20,000 row x 100 column table.  Ideally I'd put them all in one collection - and although this  comes to about 1.2GB of csv data, it's well over 2GB of mongoimport'ed data.

Question: should I program around this (60 map reduces) or is there a not-too-cumbersome engineering solution that a Mongo newbie could tackle (either w sharding or some trick that results in less bloated storage given that the underlying data is really a simple table w defined columns).

Comment: I think that the best way to work-around the 32 bit Limit, is using sharding.

Comment: honestly the best way to fix this is by upgrading to a 64 bit machine. You're really losing a ton by not doing this.

Comment: it's a bank, they don't upgrade so fast ... not my choice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go over the 2Gb limit by sharding. The 2Gb limit applies to individual mongod processes, rather than the total data in the sharded dataset.

[Here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/A+Sample+Configuration+Session) is some documentation about getting started with sharding. There is also [a Python script for setting up a sharded environment on a single machine](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-snippets/blob/master/sharding/simple-setup.py). I assume it will work on Windows.

Comment: Is there an example that shows how to configure sharding processes on a single windows machine that's easy to follow?  That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try taking a look here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Configuring+Sharding the process on windows should be very similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have 64-bit, my best recommendation is you don't. It would be too cumbersome to manage them to be under 32-bit process. It would probably be better to explore hadoop for your purpose.